# partitioning unallocated space

Tags: partitioning

I have two unallocated spaces on my HDD which I'd like to merge. A screenshot of my partitions in GParted looks like this:

[image]

I have installed Windows in those NTFS volumes. In `/dev/sda1`, I have Linux.

Please help.

**EDIT:** (How I messed up)

I have a 1TB HDD. I originally only had Linux installed. Then I installed Windows as I had to use some Adobe software for college. When I had Linux, there were three partitions.

`/dev/sda1` -> Linux installation (50GiB)

`/dev/sda2` -> Swap(2GiB)

`/dev/sda3` -> All my files(rest)

When I installed Windows, I took a backup and installed it into `/dev/sda3` by partitioning it. But apparently, the Windows installer did some partitioning in the background and created what is now `/dev/sda3`. So the rest 391.23GiB was unallocated. I removed the `swap` (which is realize now, was a huge mistake). I now want to merge both the unallocated 391.23GiB and 2GiB and use that for my files when I boot into Linux.

Comment: Ehhh, that's not going to be easy unless you make a spanned volume or something

Comment: i don't know what is in the ntfs partitions; but if they are bootable (os, recovery or whatever) - moving them could make them unbootable; if they are data it won't be an problem. for 2gb i'd not bother.  `gparted` will move them easily, just backup your data first!

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 and newer can use swapfiles instead of a swap partition.

Comment: There's a valuable lesson here - this is why many greybeards consider a backup *on the same media* to not be a 'real' backup at all.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware, you can only have 4 primary partition on a drive. Keep it simple, using Gparted you could easily and rapidly increase the current Linux partition to 52GB and create the Linux data partition in the free space at the end. Your current Linux partition has at least 40GB for storage, just add another 2GB.